# Can I create a DocumentFile with a stored Uri?

Tags: android, documentfile

I got a Uri using the following method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

like：

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A
```

Can I store this string to create a DocumentFile in application startup?
like:

```
DocumentFile.fromUri(this,Uri.pasre(str))
```

It  works on Android 6.0,but it seems invalid in higher version.
Or I should get Uri every time I start it?
I have found that some file managers do not need to get Uri via startActivityForResult(). Like RE. Are they using the shell to get a list under /storage and then stitching them into Uri?

Then use grantUriPermission() and takePersistableUriPermission() to get Uri permissions?

Sorry, my English is too bad. TT